# Turn SQL Server table variable into real table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have a temporary table created with:

```
DECLARE @tbl_fk_errors TABLE (
    id int Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1)
    , tbl_id int
    , tbl_name nvarchar(128)
    , tbl_record_id int
    , tbl_field nvarchar(20)
    , tbl_field_value nvarchar(20)
    , jnktn_field_value nvarchar(20)
    , jnktn_field nvarchar(20)
    , jnktn_tblname nvarchar(128)
```

That table will be filled in my script. Now I want to output that table into a file and found [xp_cmdshell](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/) which can do that. But that stored procedure can't take my table var because it opens a new connection to the DB (because of the "bcp").

I need to temporary save that table into my DB (and drop it after, but that's no big deal then).

**How can I quickly save a table stored in a table variable as real table in my DB?**

Comment: If you are going that route... why not just create the table, insert the data, output into file, then drop table... and forget temp table altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
into table --destination
from @table --source
```

As a bonus, wrap a transaction around this to make sure you don't leave a "dangling" table in case of an error. DDL is transactional in SQL Server. On rollback, the table will be removed.

Comment: do I have to create "table" first?

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I'll accept your answer when I'm able to, in 10 mins ;)